# Is it possible to use Combine with individual field of NSManagedObject?

Tags: swift, core-data, combine

Right now, I was able to observe changes to CoreData's NSManagedObject using

```
NotificationCenter.default
.publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: managedContext)
.sink(notification in
  guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
  //get changed object and update each field
)
```

But is there a way to subscribe with .assign and just have the change of one particular field execute a UI change directly?

Comment: You could use a `map` to extract the object and field you want to observe from the notification and then use `assign(to:on:)` to update the UI. It wouldn't save you any code though

Comment: Yes like you said that doesn’t make it better. I guess I’m looking for field level notification which doesn’t exists